# Change the request_method from GET to POST

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to transform a HTTP Request from a GET method to a POST methode in Apache.
Is it possible ?

I'm working with Dailymotion. This service send a GET method to my REST API to post some data. But I would like to receive a POST method to respect REST protocol.
I'm trying to make this transformation with Apache.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "But I would like to receive a POST method to respect REST protocol" Why would you make REST the end goal and why are you willing to jump through unneeded and strange hoops to achieve this goal?

Comment: Why would you make REST the end goal => specification of the project.
Why are you willing to jump through unneeded and strange hoops to achieve this goal? => the HTTP request sent by Dalymotion is a GET Request. We have to transform the GET in POST. An easy way to do that is Apache (no development)

Comment: I know what you are trying to do and I read what Dailymotion does in your post. My point is that it is strange to want to jump to hoops like you are trying to do. If some external service makes `GET` request consume it as a `GET` request (if if it would be possible what you want, which I doubt considering a `GET` request is totally different from `POST` request)...

Comment: I just did a sanity check: [chat log 1](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11576532#11576532) and [chat log 2](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11576541#11576541). Basically yeah what you want it counter productive and needsless and strange.

Comment: Changing the request method at the server side is unnecessary and, quite frankly, meaningless. You either need to deal with the request as it is when it arrives, or reject it. REST does not disallow the POST method, or any method, it simply disallows persistent server-side state.

Comment: The request sent by Dailymotion is a GET method because some data can be sent to this service to init value for example. But we want reroute this request to collect stats. So it is as POST method. I agree with you, it's strange. But it's not my project :) I'm only make support to help them. And I doubt also it is possible.

Comment: One more thing, I try to change the request method to respect REST standard. But it works good though.

Comment: There is no requirement within REST to use a specific method for anything. But that aside, your only hope to get this done is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET` -> `RewriteRule /path/to/file - [E=REQUEST_METHOD:POST]`, although I'm not sure if this will work at all and there's a distinct possibility it will break things.

Comment: It's not working :( Thanks for your help DaveRandom.